# Cisco RV320 cannot portforward same port twice

Tags: router, port-forwarding, port

I'm trying to port forward the port 34197 to 192.168.1.100 and 192.168.1.103 on my cisco rv320. Unfortunately in this router the ports are different services, and it won't let me add the same service twice. I've tried port triggering, but that doesn't work.. I'm trying to portforward this for a game called factorio, the game is still in pre-alpha so the multiplayer system is crap. I'm running a dedicated server on another machine, but i'd need to portforward the same port for my machine, or factorio won't be able to "connect to the peers". Should i suggest my friend brings his pc to our home? XD

Comment: Please read [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](http://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm): " There are four major problems that you may run into that would require alternatives to port forwarding.

   1/ Multiple nodes in your network that want to use the same ports." ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is a router, which receives traffic to its single outside address on port 34197, to determine to which of multiple inside addresses the traffic should be sent?

The only thing the router can see is the destination IP address and port, which would be the same for both inside addresses. You can only forward one address/port combination to one inside address.

Comment: What should i do then?

Comment: You need to use two different ports so that the router can distinguish the traffic, or you can set up tunnels with the other sites wishing to connect to you.